# I have created a new application folder under my website in IIS 7, i want to redirect traffic to new folder?

Tags: iis-7

I would like to rename my application, but instead of renaming the application in VS (which I may still do), I have created a new application folder under the website with the new application name, this seems to work just fine, what i would like to do is remove the older application folder but I don't want users who have the URL book marked to have a broken link. I tried URL Rewrite / Redirect in web.config ... see below: but I keep getting an Internal Server Error 500

```
<system.webserver>
    <rewrite>
       <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect TuitionGradeRequest">
          <match url="^(.*)/TuitionGradeRequest/(.*)$" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/LetterRequest/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webserver>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of a redirect, the server sends the updated URL to the client and it is the client now that makes a second request to the updated URL. Try this.

```
    <system.webserver>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
               <rule name="Redirect TuitionGradeRequest">
               <match url="^TuitionGradeRequest/(.*)" />
               <action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP_HOST}/LetterRequest/{R:2}" />
               </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
     </system.webserver>
```